# como salvar valor de uma variável c# em um arquivo externo?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Como posso salvar uma variável para um arquivo externo? Ele foi programado em win forms .Net Framework c#. Por exemplo:

No seguinte temos que sempre que eu apertar o botão ADD a combobox, atualmente marcada como "oi", adicionará como novo item o que estiver escrito no textbox:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list.Items.Add(name.Text);
}
```

Eu queria saber como fazer para salvar o nome de todos os Items já contidos na list (local onde está escrito "oi"), para que quando eu abrisse o programa pela segunda vez, ele permanecesse com o último nome que eu coloquei já marcado e todos os outros ainda selecionáveis.

Assim, se eu fechasse o programa no seguinte estado (Imagem 2), queria que quando eu abrisse pela segunda vez ele já estivesse com o item "oi" marcado, todos os outros itens ainda contidos para serem selecionados, e todos os itens que eu adicionasse posteriormente também fossem salvos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: OI Otaviano, o que você está descrevendo seria basicamente uma base de dados para guardar os textos digitados e um cookie para abrir o form com o ultimo texto digitado. É isto?